# Wampserver: Warning: include(wamplangues/index_english.php): failed to open stream:

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I'm getting below error while run wamp on local

> Wampserver: Warning: include(wamplangues/index_english.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\index.php on
>   line 255

How & where to get wamplangues folder?

Comment: Have you changed anything?

Comment: No but don't have that folder

Comment: Then you must have deleted that folder. Just checking it should be in `wamp\www\wamplangues`

Answer (score 1):

The `wamplangues` named folder is missing from `www` directory.

Restore it and then restart server, or perform a fresh installation of wampp.

Answer (score 0):

Wamp language folder is under the www directory where index_english.php is missing. It is already come with setup you can't find from anywhere. Try with reinstalling after taking backup all things.